# What is the maximum number of monitors for a single video card with DisplayPort outputs and MTS splitters?

Tags: graphics-card, multiple-monitors, displayport, mts

I'm looking for a video card to drive 7 or 8 displays. But when a card has multiple DisportPort 1.2+ connections, how many monitors are possible?

So far, I've found that some GPUs publish support for up to 4 displays and others claim support up to 6. But can a card with 4 DisplayPorts potentially drive 8 1080p monitors using MTS active adapters as long as the total resolution is within the card's max resolution?

For example, many GPUs claim `Max Resolution: 7680 x 4320 @ 60 Hz` and provide 4 DisplayPort connectors. Using MTS adapters, could that allow 4 1080p monitors per DisplayPort for 16 monitors total (7680/1920=4 x 4320/1080=4)? Or will the cards still limit the OS to strictly seeing only 4 (or 6) monitors?

Comment: @DavidPostill: Please consider reopening my question. I wasn't asking for shopping recommendations, but I removed all brand terms. I am asking if DisplayPort and MTS potentially support more monitors than brands explicitly publish in the marketing, however.

Answer (score 1):

Try this GPU: https://www.pny.com/NVIDIA_NVS_810_for_Eight_DP_Displays

Alternatively, using a MTS adapter, you can daisy-chain monitors
https://multimonitorcomputer.com/solved/displayport-daisy-chaining-of-3-or-4-monitors-quick-guide.php

It's important to note the resolution limit however. At 1920x1080, you can daisy-chain 4 monitors per Displayport 1.2 output.

Comment: I believe that card is two GPUs that each offer 4 displays combined onto one board. Interesting.

Comment: Regarding using MTS, I'm aware that I can do up to 4 monitors per port, but what I cannot determine is if the GPU will limit out at a certain number of monitors regardless of resolution and number of ports used. Can a 4 port card chain 4 1080p monitors each as long as the total resolution is within the max?